# Jquery Toggle throws away CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I could not find a single answer to my question online...

I am working on a website idea for my portfolio and decided to dabble with
some jQuery to make it more exciting. I have the jQuery properly linked and
working, but when I use the .toggle method, my button's CSS seems to disappear.

Here is my jQuery as it is so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".landingHideButton").click(function(){
    $(".copy-background").toggle(2000);
    $(".landingHideButton").html("Show Content");
  });
});
```

My HTML structure looks like this:

```
<div id="landing">
    <div class="copy-background">
        <h4>Header</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed leo enim, euismod nec ultrices id, ultrices vitae nisl. Aenean pharetra congue tempor. Pellentesque nisi nisl, aliquam ut pulvinar sed, tristique pretium tortor. In commodo lobortis euismod. Aliquam nisl risus, rutrum sed facilisis id, ultrices a nisi. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="landingHideButton">
        <p>Hide Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my typography css for the landingHideButton is:

```
.landingHideButton p {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #7d7d7d;
}
```

When the button is pressed, the div `copyBackground`, which contains all of the
copy is meant to toggle off/on at the speed that I set in my jQuery function.
But what I also want, is for the copy inside the button div to change from
"Hide Content" to "Show Content" so that users know to press it again to show
the content they hid. This all WORKS currently, except that the font-size CSS
and the positioning of the copy within that div all gets stripped away when you
press the button.

Does anyone know how to keep it from doing that or if there is a better/cleaner
way of accomplishing this task? Remember, I am pretty new to this so if possible,
please keep the answer simple. I understand scripting terminology to some degree
but I've never taken classes on it and only know what I learned from W3Schools.com...

See it in action at darerdesign.com for visual aid...

Answer (score 0):

You're replacing the HTML of the `.landingHideButton` div with some text that's *not* in a `P` tag, so the CSS isn't applying!

Try using a line like:

```
$(".landingHideButton").html("<p>Show Content</p>");
```

EDIT:

Or, perhaps even clearer:

```
$(".landingHideButton p").html("Show Content");
```

Comment: This worked!!! Thank you!

Honestly, I had a feeling it was some minor issue that was a result of me not knowing jquery syntax very well but I learned something out of this experience which is, I guess, for the better. =)

I appreciate the ultra fast response!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/utBg3/ **or much better** http://jsfiddle.net/K4Lge/

Also you can use toggle function and then change the content according to the open and close div

hope it helps,

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".landingHideButton").click(function(){
    $(".copy-background").toggle(2000);
    $(".landingHideButton > p").html("Show Content");
  });
});
```

**Other option**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".landingHideButton").click(function () {
        $(".copy-background").toggle(2000, function () {

            $(this).is(':visible') ? $(".landingHideButton > p").html("Hide Content") : $(".landingHideButton > p").html("Show Content");


        });

    });
});
```

Comment: This is actually even better. I just wanted something simple but after seeing this jquery in action, I'd prefer to use that for my design. Thanks!! The more you know...

Comment: @GaryDarer No worries & Glad it helped, now dont forget to accept either one of guys replies! see you around `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I would set the text in the proper element (`.landingHideButton p`) and also use a callback on toggle to set it AFTER the animation is done.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/btXFB/)

```
 $(".copy-background").toggle({
     duration: 2000,
     complete: function () {
         $(".landingHideButton p").text("Show Content");
     }
 });
```

P.S. you had it correct in your css so just a simple mistake i guess

---

---

Or this option where the hide and show are actually both there but hidden pairs and only one is visible at a time. Gently toggles button text in same duration that copy is toggled

### [Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/VY7Fm/)

```
<div class="landingHideButton">
    <p class="hide">Hide Content</p>
    <p class="show">Show Content</p>
</div>
```

---

```
$(".landingHideButton").click(function () {
    var dur = 2000;
    $(".copy-background").toggle(dur);
    $(this).find('.hide,.show').slideToggle( dur);
});
```